# Making this ruby algorithm faster

Tags: ruby, integer, permutation

Given a positive integer `n` I wish to find the largest integer `m` comprised of the digits contained in `n` that is less than `n`.

The code is to return `m` unless one of the following results obtain, in which case `-1` it should be returned.

- there is no possible variation;
- if the number of digits isn't equal to the input;
- if the first digit of the output == 0;

My code works, but it takes too long when "n" is a huge number! I believe it's because of the method #Permutation but I'm not sure. Can anyone shed a light on this? 
Here's my code

```
def next_smaller (n)
  new = n.to_s.split("").permutation.to_a.map { |n| n.join.to_i }
  res = new.sort.reverse.select { |x| x < n }.first
  res_arr = res.to_s.split("")
  res.nil? || res_arr.count != n.to_s.split("").count || res_arr[0] == 0 ? -1 : res
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide some examples of input and output?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the question. I understand you’re trying to reorganize the numbers to get the smallest number possible. So if I understand it correctly the answer will always be the numbers sorted from smallest to biggest. No need to do a permutation. Just sort the numbers. Again I don’t fully understand the problem.

Comment: My fault. I should've been more detailed. I want to find the smallest possible immediately after the input. for example: 
input 907 --> output 790
input 531 --> 513
135 -->  -1

Comment: Eddie, when responding to comments requesting clarification please edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. Questions should be self-contained, in part because not all readers read all comments, but even if they do, they have lost time in understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: I trust you don't mind my edit, and that it is correct. I don't understand your second case for returning `-1`. Do not the first and third cover all situations?

Answer (score 1):

This should generally be pretty quick.

**Code**

```
def largest(n)
  arr = n.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)
  nbr_chars = arr.size
  case nbr_chars
  when 1
    -1
  when 2
    m = arr.reverse.join.to_i
    m < 10 || m >= n ? -1 : m
  else
    (2..nbr_chars).each do |m|
      fix_digits = arr[0,nbr_chars-m]
      var_digits = arr[-m..-1]
      if var_digits == var_digits.sort
        return -1 if m == nbr_chars
      else
        a = solve_for_last_m_digits(var_digits)
        if a.nil?
          next if m < nbr_chars
          return -1
        else
          x = (fix_digits + a).join.to_i
          return x >= 10**(nbr_chars-1) ? x : -1
        end
      end
    end
    -1
  end
end
```

```
def solve_for_last_m_digits(a)
  nbr_chars = a.size
  a_as_int = a.join.to_i
  x = a.permutation(nbr_chars).max_by do |b|
    m = b.join.to_i
    m < a_as_int ? m : 0
  end
  x.join.to_i < a_as_int ? x : nil
end
```

**Examples**

```
largest                 907 #=>                 790
largest                 531 #=>                 513
largest                2638 #=>                2386 
largest               78436 #=>               78364 
largest          1783435893 #=>          1783435839 
largest  385395038954829678 #=>  385395038954828976
largest                 135 #=>                  -1
largest                 106 #=>                  -1
```

All of the calculations were effectively instantaneous.

**Explanation**

See [Array#permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) and [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

It's easiest to explain the algorithm with an example. Suppose the given integer were:

```
n = 385395038954829678
```

Had the last two digits been `87`, rather than `78`, we could simply reverse them and we'd be finished. As it is `78`, however, we conclude that there is no integer less `n` that can be obtained by permuting the last two digits of `n`.

Next we consider the last three digits, `678`. After examine the six permutations of these 3 digits we find that none are smaller than `678`, so we conclude that there is no integer less `n` that can be obtained by permuting the last three digits.

Actually I don't examine the `6` permutations of the digits of `678`. Rather I infer that the digits of that number cannot be permuted to produce a number smaller than `678` because they are *non-decreasing* (`6 <= 7 <= 8`). That is the purpose of the fragment

```
if var_digits == var_digits.sort
  return -1 if m == nbr_chars
```

If the digits of the entire string are non-decreasing (`m == nbr_chars` is `true`), we return `-1`; else `m` is incremented by one.

We therefore move on to examining the last `4` digits of the number, `9678`. As the digits comprising `9678` are not non-decreasing we know that they can be permuted to produce a number smaller than `9678` (simply swap two consecutive digits that are decreasing). After examining the 24 permutations of those four digits we find the largest number less than `9678` is `8976`. Clearly, there is no permutation of digits that would produce a number less than `n` but larger than `n` with the last 4 digits replaced by `8976`. The integer of interest is therefore obtained by replacing the last four digits of `385395038954829678` with `8976`, which is `385395038954828976`.

As soon as the last `n`-digits of `m` are *not* non-decreasing we know they can be rearranged to produce one more more numbers smaller than `m`, the largest of which will be the replacement for the last `n` digits of `m`.

The last step is to execute:

```
return x >= 10**(nbr_chars-1) ? x : -1
```

Suppose the number were `106`. The largest number less than `106` that can be obtained by permuting its digits is `x = 61` (`061`). As `61` has one or more (here one) leading zeroes, we return -1. We know there is at least one leading zéro because `nbr_chars #=> 3`, `10**(nbr_chars -1)` #=> 100`and`61 < 100`.

Comment: Thks. this works but still takes too long for a number like 1234567908

Comment: Eddie, it's now fast.

Comment: Thks. This works fast! could you explain a bit more this line? 

x >= 10**(nbr_chars-1) ? x : -1
/
Why do you check 10**(nbr_chars -1)  ?

Comment: Eddie, I edited my answer to explain the purpose of `10**(nbr_chars -1) ` (and also `if var_digits == var_digits.sort..`).

Answer (score 1):

**UPD: The code below works incorrectly with some input.**

It is better to skip the generation of all permutations. `Array#permutation` can take a block of code:

```
def fast_next_smaller(number)
  number.digits.reverse.permutation do |array|
    next if array.first == 0
    target_number = array.join.to_i
    next if target_number == number
    return target_number if target_number < number
  end
  -1
end
```

```
fast_next_smaller(907) #=> 790 
fast_next_smaller(513) #=> 153 
fast_next_smaller(153) #=> 135 
fast_next_smaller(135) #=> -1
```

Here is the benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 1000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('next_smaller') { n.times { next_smaller(rand(1_000_000..9_000_000)) } }
  x.report('fast_next_smaller') { n.times { fast_next_smaller(rand(1_000_000..9_000_000)) } }
end

       user     system      total        real
next_smaller  4.433144   0.000000   4.433144 (  4.433113)
fast_next_smaller  0.041333   0.000003   0.041336 (  0.041313)

# With a very big number
puts Benchmark.measure { fast_next_smaller(5312495046546651005896) }
  0.000000   0.000184   0.000184 (  0.000176)
```

Comment: Note `fast_next_smaller(1837) #=> 1387` whereas `1387 < 1783 < 1837`.  I believe you need the step `sort.reverse` or `sort_by { |n| -n }`. Note you don't need  `next if target_number == number`.

Comment: Thks. this is much much faster and has great readability too. But it doesn't seem to work for a number like 1234567908. Expected: 1234567890, instead got: 1234567098

Comment: I agree that we may need the sort.reverse or sort_by { |n| -n } but it makes the code too slow again...

Comment: You are right. WIthout `sort.reverse` it works incorrectly. At least you can base on it a more readable solution.

Comment: @CarySwoveland There is a UPD section at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: My apologies. I did not see the "UPD". I only looked at the code and didn't notice it had changed, but saw that it was incorrect. It still produces the same incorrect answer to `fast_next_smaller(1837)` (`1387`) which I mentioned in my first comment. You need to test with integers having more than three digits. In the general case you cannot avoid enumerating permutations of digits, but not necessarily permutations of all digits.

Comment: No problem. I agree that it is not necessarily permutations of all digits. I tested on bigger integers, unfortunately, randomly I chose numbers that were produced the proper results. If I find an appropriate solution I'll update my answer.